# Php/Mysql: Database class and dependency injection

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, dependency-injection

I'm trying to adopt dependency injection pattern to a mid-scale project that I have been working on. Most of my classes interact with database on some level and instead of instantiating a pdo object inside each class, I instantiate a single pdo object on controller level and inject this object to classes that require a database connection. This way, all classes are using the same connection and the whole process is making the unit testing pretty easy.

However, things get a little bit complex when I try to use transaction with these classes. Our database is heavily de-normalized and each action requires multiple inserts/updates from different classes. To give a basic example, let's say we have the classes below:

```
    class student{
        public function addCourse($pdo,$course){
            //$pdo->execute();
        }
    }

    class course{
        public function incrementStudentCount($pdo){
            //$pdo->execute();
        }
    }
```

As you see, both addCourse and incrementStudentCount methods must work in a single transaction mode.However,student and course classes are not aware of whether a transaction started or not in $pdo object. They don't know if a rollback is required in case a problem occurs.

I thought of creating a PDO wrapper class and using this class for database interactions. This way, I can keep the transaction state inside this class. Basically, it looks something like this:

```
    class PDOWrapper {
        private $transactionStarted=false;
        private $pdo;
        public function __construct($pdo){
            $this->pdo=$pdo;
        }
        public function startTransaction(){
            $this->transactionStarted=true; 
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction()
        }
        public function query($query){
            try{
                //$this->db->execute($query);
            }
            catch(PDOException e){
                if($this->transactionStarted){
                    $this->db->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, I'm not sure this approach is the way to go. So, what would you suggest?

Comment: So whats the issue you have or are trying to overcome with the code you came up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that your classes should not know what is going on in the other class / DB. None of that matters, all the `student` and `user` classes are concerned with are inserting to the database.

It shouldn't matter if there's a transaction or not: they should still be doing the exact same thing they'd be doing regardless, which is inserting rows. I'd recommend you have a controller that takes care of both tasks, like so:

```
$pdo->startTransaction();
//However you instantiate the course object, do it here
$course = new Course;
//Same with student
$student = new Student;
$student->addCourse($pdo, $course);
$course->incrementStudentCount($pdo);
$pdo->commit();
```

When you commit to the database, all your queries will go through. You can rollback in case of an error like so:

```
try
{
    $pdo->startTransaction();
    //Code
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $pdo->rollback();
}
```